# Accidentally broke the network adapter on my VM by telling it to use wrong IP

Tags: azure

I accidentally told my network adapter to use a bad ip address in my Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) properties. A big oops look spread across my face as I pressed the OK button and immediately got disconnected from my remote session. Naturally I can't remote back in and even azure can't reboot the vm. Is there any way I can recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

So things I would do include:
1. [Redeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-redeploy-to-new-node)
2. Try to change VM ip using the portal\powershell
3. Delete the VM and deploy new one using the same os\data disks.